# How to get magento Category hierarchy?

Tags: category

I want all category in magento like under given structure.

```
parent1
   par2
     child1
   par3
     child2
     child3
     child4
   par4
parent2
   par5
     child5
   par6
     child6
parent3 
parent4
```

Can any one help?

Comment: There's no easy way to get the entire category tree, what is it you are trying to do exactly?

Comment: `getStoreCategories() in Mage/catalog/block/Navigation ` returns top categories, then use `getChildrenCategories()` to get category children.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this script to Display top level categories and subcategories

```
<?php $_helper = Mage::helper('catalog/category') ?>
<?php $_categories = $_helper->getStoreCategories() ?>
<?php $currentCategory = Mage::registry('current_category') ?>
<?php if (count($_categories) > 0): ?>
    <ul>
        <?php foreach($_categories as $_category): ?>
            <li>
                <a href="<?php echo $_helper->getCategoryUrl($_category) ?>">
                    <?php echo $_category->getName() ?>
                </a>
                <?php $_category = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($_category->getId()) ?>
                <?php $_subcategories = $_category->getChildrenCategories() ?>
                <?php if (count($_subcategories) > 0): ?>
                    <ul>
                        <?php foreach($_subcategories as $_subcategory): ?>
                            <li>
                                <a href="<?php echo $_helper->getCategoryUrl($_subcategory) ?>">
                                    <?php echo $_subcategory->getName() ?>
                                </a>
                            </li>
                        <?php endforeach; ?>
                    </ul>
                <?php endif; ?>
            </li>
        <?php endforeach; ?>
    </ul>
<?php endif; ?>
```

If you want to get level 3 or leave 4 categories you need to repeat this :

```
<?php $_subcategories = $_category->getChildrenCategories() ?>
                    <?php if (count($_subcategories) > 0): ?>
                        <ul>
                            <?php foreach($_subcategories as $_subcategory): ?>
                                <li>
                                    <a href="<?php echo $_helper->getCategoryUrl($_subcategory) ?>">
                                        <?php echo $_subcategory->getName() ?>
                                    </a>
                                </li>
                            <?php endforeach; ?>
                        </ul>
                    <?php endif; ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on Ahmed's answer, here is a basic recursive method to list subcategories starting at category ID 1 (Default Category).

```
function showSubCategories($categoryId)
{
    if ($categoryId) {
        $category = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($categoryId);
        $subCats = $category->getChildrenCategories();
        if (count($subCats) > 0) {
            echo '<ul>';
            foreach ($subCats as $subCat) {
                echo "<li><a href=\"{$subCat->getUrl()}\">{$subCat->getName()}</a>";
                showSubCategories($subCat->getId());
                echo '</li>';
            }
            echo '</ul>';
        }
    }
}

showSubCategories(1);
```